# Okay I am confused on about 2 things with this bot I made

Tags: python, discord.py

Okay so yesterday I made this thing called a sign bot. Sign bots are more like role bots but they are for football leagues so If I were to say say that :49ers: is my logo emoji, I say <:49ers:123456789> sign @User#0001 it would reply back saying "@User#0001 has been signed to <:49ers:123456789> I was informed you have to use the emoji ids. So lemme cut to the chase on my issue... So after I created this bot I decided to test it as soon as I test it I am pretty sure

```py
from discord.utils import get
```

has to be imported, well I import it and it says this heres the image:
[image]

so I find that odd when I have this line of code that uses that import:

```py
@bot.event
  async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('<:SF1:763564017456644116> sign'):
      role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name='San Francisco 49ers')
      member = message.mentions[0]
      await member.add_roles(role)
      await message.channel.send(f'{member.mention} **Successfully signed to** <:SF1:763564017456644116>')
```

I wonder if this is the reason why when I test the `on_message` command nothing happens, also I find this strange comment in there as well were the offer `on_message` event starts:
[image]

well if any of you could help me out I would be happy.

Comment: You used `discord.utils.get`, but you never used `get`, so you didn't need to import it.

Comment: You're getting the cyclomatic complexity comment because you have too many if statements in one function. You can separate your commands by using the @bot.command decorator and putting them in different functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea about discord bots, but you can either get rid of the

```
from discord.utils import get
```

line, or you can call `get()` just by specifying the function name, without the full path:

```
role = get(...)
```

This will work because you had already imported the whole discord module in line 1.

Comment: edit: i dont know why but it only works for the first few times the message is invoked? then it doesnt role anyone anymore. please help.